# Ruby both on front end and back end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, sails.js, publish-subscribe

I am trying to figure out whether I can build a web application completely on Ruby stack.

I am looking for following architecture:

> Frontend <--- Websockets with Pub/Sub ---> Backend

On top of that, I really like Rails approach with "convention over configuration". As result, I am looking for some "opinionated" framework which will handle this scenario.

I know that it's easier to achieve with Javascript stack. As example using [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/).

However, it's experiment. So, I am not looking for the most efficient solution.

Has anybody build anything like that? What would be a reasonable set of libraries/frameworks to build something like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said it's an experiment, I would recommend you to try out [Volt](http://voltframework.com/). It uses [Opal](http://opalrb.org/), which transcribes Ruby to JS and has reactive synchronization which Meteor.js is famous for. Also there are a lot of Railisms and you will find yourself in familiar waters very quickly.

Both technologies are not quite there yet, but there is a lot of hype around them and they will for sure play a big role in Ruby's near future.

Answer (score 1):

As @ndn mentioned, [Volt](http://voltframework.com) is interesting... But, it seems to me that the part I would adopt would be the [Opal](http://opalrb.org) core for a front end.

Volt is too opinionated for me.

I would like to add my own pet project to the table, [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi), which can be both an independent framework and can also run together within a Rails app by using the Iodine server.

I feel that [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) has a much better balance between 'convention over configuration' and code-freedom. It manages the backend by automatically mapping websocket broadcasts/unicasts to their respective controller and method (`broadcast :method, arg1, arg2...`) and automatically maps Redis channels to controllers (or global multicasting) for easy scaling.

At the same time, Plezi does nothing for the front end and assume nothing regarding the front end. This is by design, both for better security (doesn't auto-trust incoming network data) and to allow for for the variety of possible clients such as native apps (iOS, android), browsers, scripts etc'... This would be where Opal can come in (or RubyMotion).